# What sys.ku$ stands for?

Tags: oracle

There are some types with "sys.ku$_" prefix, but is that "ku" abbreviation of something?
Just nice to know things :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**My suspicion**:  They're struct definitions in the Oracle kernel, as the V$ objects are public interfaces to dynamic performance information, the GV$ objects are the cross-instance version of the V$ objects, and the X$ objects are the actual data in the kernel.  (Think of them as a linked-list of structs, as that's how a lot of them seem to be implemented.  Oracle's doesn't call them, for example, "LRU chains" by accident.)

**My opinion**:  You don't need to know what they are, and you should never ever depend on them, because Oracle can and will changed them without any notification.

Comment: Is it so that you should never use any objects own by sys? Only using stuff included in internal packages like in dbms_*? We are heavily using views of sys for example. Are Oracle going to change those or are those frozen to ensure backward compatibility?

Comment: The X$ and KU$ objects are undocumented.  The objects owned by sys that are documented (such as the V$ views, described in the Database Reference) can and should be used.  Oracle changes those very slowly, adding functionality but never removing it; that's the main reason why LONG remains a supported datatype - it exists in V$ views.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it stands for "knowledge unit"? In Knowledge Management systems:

> a KU is anything worth storing that
>   may help things to be done better in
>   the future: help, best practice
>   guidelines etc.

Anyway I don't have any further ideas about this abbreviation etymology :)

Comment: I also want to use common types and do things with best practices, but I don't want to use anything which looks weird and I don't even know what it stands for. Of course it's easier to write ku$_vcnt than for example something like dbms_utility.varchar2_nested_table_type. But code readability it's better with long name which says directly what it represent.

Comment: @oocce I fully agree with you, but these "ku$" types and views are not widely used - I suppose - so that is not a common speck in the eye

Answer (score 0):

I was always of the understanding that "ku" in the Oracle ku$ objects stood for "kernelutil".

Answer (score -1):

A system defined Type.

Not sure what the Ku stands for.

Comment: And btw it's type of sys not system. They are different users.

Answer (score -3):

its collection.

```
SELECT KU$OBJECT_NUMSET(1,2,4) FROM DUAl;
```

> ANS : 1
>         2
>         3
>
> Blockquote